# Access and SQL date comparison

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 front and sql2008 back. I am using a date parameter on a form and a view for the report. It doesn't give me any data. It's not understanding the access date paramter. I have tried converting the date in sql, but still no data. Here is the code I am using.

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
LocationRpt
End Sub

Private Sub LocationRpt()

Dim frm As Form_frmSecRpt
Dim strSQL As String
Dim SchDt As Date
Set frm = Form_frmSecRpt
SchDt = frm.txtDate
strSQL = "Select * From vw_SecLocationWO Where ReSchDt =" & SchDt
Me.RecordSource = strSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, although I know nothing of ms-access-2010, to get the best out of Stack Overflow you will need to provide your current code and ask people why it's not working!

Answer (score 1):

Access SQL expects date values to be delimited with hash marks (`#`), so try this instead:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM vw_SecLocationWO WHERE ReSchDt = #" & Format(SchDt, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"
```

Comment: Just figured it out.  "SELECT * FROM vw_SecLocationWO WHERE ReSchDt = '" & Format(SchDt, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'". Use single quote instead of pound sign. I neglected to say that this was in an Access project.